# CakePHP static pages (without entity) but with dynamic content

Tags: php, controller, url-routing, cakephp

I have a few pages that is not connected with entities (index page, terms of use page, email page).

**Detailed description:** In CakePHP, when you want to have a static page (such as index for example), you should use the `PagesController` (not connected to any entity). However, my static pages have dynamic content, as the index page (the `navbar` is dynamic: it has the name of the user when logged in, and special buttons).

**1st:** To do this, I create a `CustomStaticPagesController` controller (which is not connected to any entity), in which I created the methods (index, email, termos-de-servico).

**2nd:** I edited the `routes.php` references to the actions without the standard localhost/controller/action now this localhost/action.

**Question:** How can I improve (do it right) the two points referred to above? Any other point to improve ?

**CustomStaticPagesController controller code:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\AppClasses\FormatFormValues\FormatContactForm;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Email\Email;

class CustomStaticPagesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');

        $this->loadModel('Categories');
        $categories = $this->Categories->getAllCategories();

        $this->loadModel('SubCategories');
        $subCategories = $this->SubCategories->getAllSubCategories();
        $subCategoriesName = $this->SubCategories->listAllSubCategories();

        $this->loadModel('UserTypes');
        $userTypes = $this->UserTypes->listSubCategories();

        $this->loadModel('Banners');
        $fullBanners = $this->Banners->full();
        $smallBanners = $this->Banners->small();

        $this->loadModel('Products');
        $productsBestSeller = $this->Products->getProductTrendByColumn('sold', 0);
        $productsNewer = $this->Products->getProductTrendByColumn('created', 0);
        $productsMostPopular = $this->Products->getProductTrendByColumn('visited', 0);

        $this->loadModel('Offers');
        $offers = $this->Offers->offersRecursive();

        $this->loadModel('News');
        $news = $this->News->getRecentNews();

        $this->set(compact('userId', 'username', 'userTypes', 'smallBanners',
            'fullBanners', 'offers', 'news', 'categories', 'subCategories',
            'subCategoriesName', 'productsBestSeller', 'productsNewer',
            'productsMostPopular'));
    }

    public function perguntasFrequentes()
    {
        $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');

        $this->loadModel('UserTypes');
        $userTypes = $this->UserTypes->listSubCategories();

        $this->set(compact('userId', 'username', 'userTypes'));
    }

    public function termosDeServico()
    {
        $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');

        $this->loadModel('UserTypes');
        $userTypes= $this->UserTypes->listSubCategories();

        $this->set(compact('userId', 'username', 'userTypes'));
    }

    public function politicasDePrivacidade()
    {
        $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');

        $this->loadModel('UserTypes');
        $userTypes = $this->UserTypes->listSubCategories();

        $this->set(compact('userId', 'username', 'userTypes'));
    }

    public function email()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $username = $this->Auth->user('username');

            $this->loadModel('UserTypes');
            $userTypes = $this->UserTypes->listSubCategories();

            $this->set(compact('userId', 'username', 'userTypes'));

        }else if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            Email::configTransport('gmail', [
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => 587,
                'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'className' => 'Smtp',
                'tls' => true
            ]);

            $email = new Email();
            $email->transport('gmail');
            $email->from(['email@gmail.com' => 'Store Site'])
                ->to('email@outlook.com')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->subject(
                    FormatContactForm::getSubject(
                        $this->request->data['subject'],
                        ['suffix' => ' | Store Site']
                    )
                )
                ->send(
                    FormatContactForm::getMessage(
                        $this->request->data,
                        ['uppercaseLabel' => true]
                    )
                );

            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'index']);
        }
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'perguntasFrequentes', 'email', 'politicasDePrivacidade', 'termosDeServico']);
    }
}
```

**routes.php code**

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'index']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'index']);

    $routes->connect('/termos-de-servico', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'termosDeServico']);

    $routes->connect('/politicas-de-privacidade', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'politicasDePrivacidade']);

    $routes->connect('/perguntas-frequentes', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'perguntasFrequentes']);

    $routes->connect('/email', ['controller' => 'CustomStaticPages', 'action' => 'email']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Comment: Every question on Code Review needs at least a language tag, which is, in this case, [tag:php].

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to place the **loadModel()** calls in the **initialize()** function, like so:

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadModel('Model');
}
```

That way you get no redundancy and you have them at the same spot.
Easier to maintain.

There are different ways to include your models in the controller, a different way would be to call `Cake\ORM\TableRegistry('Table');`

I'm mainly using TableRegistry when im creating custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

For Index page, Navigations and other widgets use Cells http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (why are Cells an advantage?) so that the author can learn from your thought process.